# Como evitar que wordpress cambie mi DIV por IS_PAGE

Tags: php, wordpress

Estoy desarrollando un shortcode para wordpress, y todo funciona bien, excepto que cuando el programa intenta escribir la etiqueta DIV, en HTML me aparece como **is_page** o **is_archive**,
Mi problema es que quiero hacer aparecer texto sobre una imagen al pasar el cursor por encima, y con esas etiquetas, parece que no funciona. Alguien sabe como hacerlo?

Comment: Por favor edita tu respuesta añadiendo todo el código que estás usando y explica al detalle todo el proceso para poder ayudarte.

Comment: gracias, pero abandono la pregunta. He descubierto que wordpress me permite insertar directamente etiquetas DIV, el problema estaba cuando utilizaba una función mía para construir la etiqueta. Aunque lo hace correctamente, en la salida de Wordpress aparecía is_page o is_archive....según el servidor...